# Is there a way to embed a java application or JApplet into a website anymore?

Tags: java, html, applet

With Chrome and other browsers not supporting Java applets, is there anyway to actually add a Java app. or applet to a website?
Maybe through PHP or within Javascript?

Would prefer to not have to use software etc. just to get an application to show on a website.

Comment: Applets are dead. If you have an old applet, then no. There is no way with php or javascript to make it not be dead. What kind of "java application" is this?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch do you know if Java web start and JNLP are dead? If OP's application is based on Swing or AWT, that could be an option.

Comment: @James_Parsons [Today](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web) yes. Although in [11](https://www.techworld.com.au/article/634384/javafx-will-removed-from-java-jdk/) who knows?

Comment: Java Web Start will die. Oracle recommends jlink. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javaclientroadmapupdate2018mar-4414431.pdf

Comment: @ElliottFrisch. The 2nd link is referring to Java-FX (and as an aside, I was waiting to hear something like that!). JWS (for launching AWT, Swing or Java-FX) is to be [deprecated in Java 9](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-deprecated-features-3745636.html) - just like applets.

Answer (score 1):

No. Oracle is set to [deprecate applets and Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/9-deprecated-features-3745636.html) in Java 9.

Browser manufacturers have already removed support for the Java plug-in, meaning applets will not launch, and even the process of launching a JWS app. has become more complicated for the user to work with (to the point where it is no longer practical to use).

See also [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).